# AWS Linux crontab job isnt executing script

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron

First of all I've tried multiple solutions I know there are several posts with similar problems none of those were a solution for me.

I have a Clojure application which is started using:

```
lein run -m tsdb-delete.core
```

The plan is to execute this every day at midnight I want to avoid using Clojure based cron libraries and this is a very light weight application.

I created the following script (`start.sh`):

```
/usr/bin/lein run -m tsdb-delete.core
```

which calls this script at run time (`delete.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Deleting:" $1
OUTPUT="$(sudo /opt/opentsdb/build/tsdb scan --delete 30d-ago 7d-ago sum $1)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

If I call './start.sh' manually it all works as expected and I see console output.

`start.sh` is located at `/home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/start.sh` and `delete.sh` is located at `/home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/delete.sh`

I have added the following to me crontab using `crontab -e`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ec2-user/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/5 * * * * /home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/start.sh > /var/tmp/tsdb-delete.out
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

`* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` is used for debugging purposes, the contents of `env.output` are as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=ec2-user
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ec2-user/bin
PWD=/home/ec2-user
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ec2-user
LOGNAME=ec2-user
_=/bin/env
```

and if I run `env` in the terminal myself I get the following:

```
HOSTNAME=ip-xx-xx-xx-xx
LESS_TERMCAP_md=
LESS_TERMCAP_me=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=xxxxxxxxx
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=ec2-user
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
LESS_TERMCAP_us=
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ec2-user
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ec2-user/bin
PWD=/var/tmp
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ec2-user
LOGNAME=ec2-user
SSH_CONNECTION= xxxxxxx
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LESS_TERMCAP_se=
_=/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/ec2-user
```

The key environment attributes seem to match, and in `var/cron/log` I see the following:

```
Oct 28 11:45:01 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx CROND[23591]: (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/start.sh > /var/tmp/tsdb-delete.out)
Oct 28 11:45:01 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx CROND[23592]: (ec2-user) CMD (env > /tmp/env.output)
```

and in `/var/spool/mail/` I don't see any error messages being thrown and the file `/var/tmp/tsdb-delete.out` is not created.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can run `start.sh` manually as `ec2-user`? Have you tried the "It still doesn't work!" command from the crontab [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)? (Modified to set any necessary environment variables as found in your `env` dump?)

Comment: can you run /home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/start.sh > /var/tmp/tsdb-delete.out manually? guessing a permission issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` requires a tty, which doesn't exist while running a cron. ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49078/42232),[2](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11610))

Here's a better solution; place this in `/etc/cron.d/tsdb-delete`:

```
*/5 * * * * root /home/ec2-user/tsdb-delete/start.sh > /var/tmp/tsdb-delete.out
```

This requires having the execute bit set on `start.sh`. Also note the `/etc/cron` entries take a sixth argument which is the user.

It's also bad form to use something like `sudo` in a cron, and generally using a user cron (`crontab -e`) is not terribly friendly for configuration management. The above fixes these problems. Still, I'd recommend moving the script to a safer location (since it's running via root), and since it's root you can easily send output to `/var/log/` (and append it):

```
*/5 * * * * root /opt/tsdb-delete/start.sh >> /var/log/tsdb-delete.out
```